# is there a node.js framework offering both authorisation and authentication like spring-security?

Tags: node.js, authentication, spring-security, authorization

There are frameworks like

1.passport
2.everyauth for authentication

1.connect-roles for autherisation

Is there any framework like spring-security offering both in one go?